# Automated Tests Don't show up in Session FrontEnd. Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, unit-testing, unreal-engine4

Sorry for bothering you guys but i have been having problems in trying to make some tests to show up in the automated test framework. I wrote two basic tests (c++) just to see what would happen in a plugin but i can't see them, when i open the session frontend. Can somebody help ? This is probably a minor error ...

Thank you very much in advance!

```
#include "FMyTestUtils.h"
#include "Misc/AutomationTest.h"
#include "Tests/AutomationCommon.h"
#include "PlayableArea.h"
#include "UnrealEd.h"


IMPLEMENT_SIMPLE_AUTOMATION_TEST(FPACountTest, "Tests.FTrialTest", EAutomationTestFlags::EditorContext | EAutomationTestFlags::EngineFilter);

bool FPACountTest::RunTest(const FString& Parameters) 
{
    AutomationOpenMap("/Game/StarterContent/Maps/FTest_CountPAS.FTest_CountPAS");

    UWorld* World = FMyTestUtils::GetWorld();
    TestNotNull("Check if World is properly created", World);
    if (!World) return false;

    int32 PACount = 0;


    for (TActorIterator<APlayableArea> It(World); It; ++It) {
        PACount++;
    }

    TestTrue("Check if there are 4 PAS on the level", PACount == 3);

    ADD_LATENT_AUTOMATION_COMMAND(FExitGameCommand);

    return true;

}
```

I also tried the one in the Unreal Documentation:

```
#include "MyBot.h"



IMPLEMENT_SIMPLE_AUTOMATION_TEST(FPlaceholderTest, "TestGroup.TestSubgroup.Placeholder Test", EAutomationTestFlags::EditorContext | EAutomationTestFlags::EngineFilter);

bool FPlaceholderTest::RunTest(const FString& Parameters)
{
    // Make the test pass by returning true, or fail by returning false.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you describe more what help you need?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much ! Actually i just want to know what i'm doing wrong for them not to show up in the automation test framework from unreal engine.  The simple test, the second one is copied from the Unreal documentation so im wondering what i could be doing wrong. The plugin is also enabled so i just cant seem to wrap my head around this....

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue! I was adding the classes in the visual studio so the Unreal couldn't find them. I just had to move the classes from the file "Intermediate" and put it in the "source" and generate the visual studio project files again and then build and it showed up!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to check, one is Test Plugin of UE should be enabled, the other is the module where your test code lives should be include in uproject file.

If your module exactly is in uproject, maybe you need to regenerate your vs project.

Here is a way to regenerate vs project, which don’t use method of right click uproject

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/generate-cpp-project-couldnt-find-unrealbuildtool/231288/15?page=3

Basically you run cmd, cd to your UBT folder, run `UnrealBuildTool.exe -projectfiles -project="path to your project\project name.uproject" -game -engine -rocket -progress`